# Django - How to get the prefix for each form in formset

Tags: django, django-forms

In a formset with multiple forms, each form gets a unique id like "MyForm-0_form" whereas MyForm is a the common prefix and 0 is the iterated form index.

Let's say the template looks like this

**template.py:**

```
<form action="" method="POST>
{% for form in formset %}
{{form}
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

When the form has been submitted I would like to do something like the following:

**view.py:**

```
[...]
if request.method == "POST":
  if formset.isValid():
    for form in formset:
      print form.currentFormID #here i get stuck. What I would like to yield: MyForm-0
```

Comment: You want this because you use two different models? Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003984/django-how-to-save-a-formset-based-on-two-models

Comment: I want to do this because I only want to use one of the forms in formset. 
Unfortunately I can't work with form_hasChanged() because I inject many data into the form, which changes virtually all of them upfront. Still, I only need one of them.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if formset.is_valid():
        for form in formset:
            print form.prefix
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why I dont find such properties on official website.

Answer (score 1):

Use the prefix argument in your form instance.

```
form1 = FormFirst(request.POST, prefix='form1') 
form2 = FormSecond(request.POST, prefix='form2')
```

The advantage of using prefix is that you don't need to manually rename the fields

Comment: Thanks, This is correct for multiple different forms in a view. But question was to find prefix for a given subform in formsets. sha256 correctly answered that.